# Apache + External IP from LAN + random image = nothing

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, ip, lan

First let me say a bit about my configuration:

- Apache working on PC-1 at port 80
- PC-1 has a static IP
- DMZ in router set to IP of PC-1

When I try to access any image on my webserver using the external IP of PC-1, with any of my computers in the same LAN of PC-1, they won't appear.

- When I try to use the local IP of PC-1 it works correctly
- When I try to use the external IP, using a computer outside of the LAN of PC-1, it works correctly
- When I try to use the external IP, using any computer inside of the LAN of PC-1, it **doesn't work**

The URL of the image **is correct**, it doesn't work even if I try to use the direct link (example: http://EXTERNAL-IP/teste.jpg).

I also tried direct links for other content type like .rar or .txt, these both work correctly in the same situation I mention above. Pages also appear correctly (without the images of course).

Also, there are no errors in Apache error.log and I can find the GET request in Apache access.log

**In short:**

Only **image files** hosted on my server cannot be displayed if I use the **external IP** using a computer **inside my LAN**

EDIT: Some more information.

- Tried with different browsers.
- Tried turning off firewalls.

EDIT 2: It's not the same problem and thus not the same question as the one marked as duplicated: Only images didn't work, html/php/txt content would load with external IP, unlike the "duplicated" question.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: @DavidPostill If I understand correctly, **NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning** not working correctly on my router wouldn't allow me to access anything that I have on Apache, right? 

That's not my case, since html/php pages do load or even other file types.

By the way, my router is an ASUS RT-AC66U with Asuswrt-Merlin firmware and it does appear it supports NAT Loopback.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: It is required to access a local server from a local machine via the wan ip address.

Comment: I misread the question and didn't realise you only had the problem with images.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: In chrome (I also tried other browsers and they are the same):  net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Have something interesting in apache access and error logs?

Comment: Nothing, just the usual GET access and no errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been a hiccup that mysteriously resolved itself after rebooting.  The problem can no longer be replicated.

Comment: David, it might not be a duplicate, but it still sounds like a hiccup that can't be explained or reproduced.  Is there still a problem to solve or a reliable solution that other people with a similar problem could use?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by... rebooting the host machine, I don't know why but it started working after it.